# How to download a snappy.parquet file from s3 using Boto in Python

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto, parquet, snappy

I'm new to this, and trying to download a snappy.parquet file from Amazon s3 I can later convert to CSV file. 
I tried working with the following example I've found online, and I get an empty folder. can anyone please help me?

```
import boto
import sys, os
from boto.s3.key import Key
from boto.exception import S3ResponseError

DOWNLOAD_LOCATION_PATH =""
BUCKET_NAME = ""
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= ""
AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = ""
conn  = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

#goto through the list of files
bucket_list = bucket.list()
for l in bucket_list:
    key_string = str(l.key)
    s3_path = DOWNLOAD_LOCATION_PATH + key_string

    try:
        print ("Current File is ", s3_path)
        l.get_contents_to_filename(s3_path)
    except (OSError, S3ResponseError) as e:
        pass
        # check if the file has been downloaded locally
        if not os.path.exists(s3_path):
            try:
                os.makedirs(s3_path)
            except OSError as exc:
                # let guard againts race conditions
                import errno

                if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                    raise
```

Answer (score 0):

The script you are using appears to recursively download the contents of the specified S3 bucket (`BUCKET_NAME`) to the specified local directory (`DOWNLOAD_LOCATION_PATH`). FWIW, I notice this script looks like it comes from [here](https://gist.github.com/freewayz/38f850a7b0c49f8e31c951c2eaf2c2c1).

The "Current File is ..." output line should show you the progress of these files being written. One problem you might be having is due to this line:

```
s3_path = DOWNLOAD_LOCATION_PATH + key_string
```

If you had specified `DOWNLOAD_LOCATION_PATH` at the top as a directory without a trailing '/' character, e.g. like this:

```
DOWNLOAD_LOCATION_PATH = '/tmp/my_dir'
```

then the files being downloaded would be written not underneath the `/tmp/my_dir` directory, but directly in `/tmp/` with a `my_dir` prefix on each filename! You can fix this by changing this line to:

```
    s3_path = os.path.join(DOWNLOAD_LOCATION_PATH, key_string)
```

Other than that, the script appears to work alright. You may want to add this line at the very top:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

if you are still using Python 2.x, otherwise the print output will look a bit odd (`print` will think you are printing a 2-Tuple).

Your question also makes it sound like you really only want/need to download a single file from the bucket -- if so, this isn't really a great script to be using, since it's downloading everything.